# How to add a transition when appending a div inside of a div tag

Tags: html, css

I am making a web app for texting. There's an input box for text and when a text is sent, a new `<div>` tag is created under an existing `<div>` tag. The code looks like this:

```js
function send() {
  const chatbox = document.querySelector(".chatbox");
  var input = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if (!input) return;
  const newtext = document.createElement("div");
  newtext.classList.add("mytexts");
  newtext.innerHTML = input;
  chatbox.appendChild(newtext);
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox"> </div>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Type...">
  <button id="send" onclick="send()">Send</button>
</div>
```

Every time there's a new text, a new `<div class="mytexts">` is created inside the `<div class="chatbox">`. **Is there a way to add some cool transition effect when a new `<div>` is created** so that it looks good when a new text is sent?

Comment: The transition will happen so quick it will only display for a split second also wont this slow down the process of opening new div for next text message if you make the transition last longer? it will look cool but it will look like the program is slow? why not just display message sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the new div and give it an animation that scales it from 0 to 1

```js
function send() {
  const chatbox = document.querySelector(".chatbox");
  var input = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if (!input) return;
  const newtext = document.createElement("div");
  newtext.classList.add("mytexts");
  newtext.innerHTML = input;
  chatbox.appendChild(newtext);
}
```

```css
@keyframes scale-up {
  0% {transform: scale(0)}
  100% {transform: scale(1)}
}
.mytexts {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: scale-up 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox"> </div>
<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Type...">
  <button id="send" onclick="send()">Send</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use gsap for animations:
https://greensock.com/gsap/

I don't know what kind of effect you're looking for but just adding a line of gsap animation after appending the child should do the trick:
`gsap.from(newText, {x: -100, opacity: 0, duration: 0.5, ease: 'back'})`

where the first parameter specifies the object to be animated and the second one the css properties it will animate from.